# What are some examples of how the Empire helped the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

In almost every piece of Star Wars media, it's shown how the Empire has drafted people, razed lands, and made the galaxy an uninhabitable place for millions of people.  However, they obviously weren't 100% terrible, as they had some people who believed in them and weren't just scared.  What are some examples of ways that the Empire did help the galaxy?  Or was it all just scare tactic?

Comment: They provided employment for a *lot* of superweapon-obsessed mad scientists...

Comment: They killed a lot of gungans. So there's that.

Comment: [Aqueducts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qc7HmhrgTuQ)

Comment: The Empire eradicated unemployment by drafting people to work in the war industry or fight in the military. They also put humans in their "rightful" place as the most important species (there are no non-humans in important positions in the Empire). Maybe a parallel to Nazi Germany, which did much the same things.

Comment: @KlausÆMogensen - "*there are no non-humans in important positions in the Empire"* (Aside from Thrawn. Who's not a human.)

Comment: You mean apart from better sanitation, the medicine, education, wine, public order, irrigation, roads, a fresh water system, and public health?  Sorry, I couldn't not.

Comment: @Cadence Doomsday device? Ah! Now the ball's in Farnsworth's court!

Answer (score 6):

Palpatine never lied about the purpose of his empire.
It was to bring order and stability to the galaxy.

Before the clone wars Episode 1 & 2 showed that the government has become inefficient and corrupt (Even before Palpatine s meddling). So the empire fixed the problems their democratic system had...by just simply removing the democracy. A common criticism on the republic (And the Jedi) were that they drop by where there was a conflict, made it stop but did nothing about the long term ramifications until it all blew up again and they just went back to do the same all over. The Kaleesh for example (Grievous his species) got the short end of the stick when the Republic sanctioned them for doing a counter attack on the Yam'rii who invaded and enslaved them. Another Example would be factions like the Trade Federation becoming to powerful and freely able to bully surrounding systems because the Republic was to inefficient and corrupt with dealing it.

And as we see in the Mandalorian, as soon as the empire fell and the Stormtroopers were gone slavers and other criminals organizations seized power again... for comparison look at The Hutt before and after the formation of the empire, they were but a husk of their former glory.

The Empire was a dictatorship, but for the people lowest on the food chain they were a "slight" improvement because at least the empire cracked harder down on the criminals who would exploit those people.

Comment: Are you suggesting the Hutts were weaker during the Empire, and that was a good thing? Or that it was a bad thing?

Comment: @TylerH it was a good thing, seeing the Hutt preyed on the weak, who were better protected by the Empire.